# Where should I store .clang-format file?

Tags: c, clang

I have a customized .clang-format file.
I want to run clang-format --dry-run with that .clang-format file.
so I made a directory clang-format_test and I put .clang-format file in that directory.
and I made directory inside clang-format_test directory named test, and I put example.c file into test directory.
clang-format_test > .clang-format, test > example.c
am I using right way? I can't check clang-format is using customized file or default option.
I want to use like `clang-format --dry-run -style=file ./test/example.c`
i

Answer (score 2):

You're doing everything right. Put your `.clang-format` file in the root of the project, so it will be used when calling `clang-format` from the root or any subdirectory of your project. You can also choose not to specify the `-style=file` option.

If you need to change the formatting of some subdirectories of the project, you can simple put a new `.clang-format` file in this subdirectory.

To make sure you are using the correct style, call `clang-format --dump-config`, which will show the contents of your current configuration.

Comment: oh thanks! I will check either it works well

Comment: I called clang-format --dump-config. and compared with customized clang-format file. but they are different. what should I do?

Comment: @min I think the problem is that `clang-format --dump-config` prints the default values for options not specified in your custom `.clang-format`. Carefully check the value of the parameters you have changed. If it doesn't help I want to see the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: your answer is exactly right. thanks a lot. your answer helped me so much. thanks again. and have a nice day!!  :)